# Heroku pipeline promote - pull to repository

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have on Heroku 2 apps (forked) inside a pipeline. When I push and deploy the staging app and promote it to production, it works perfectly but I do not see it in my remote git repository (in Sourcetree when I fetch, the production remote is not changed).

How do I get the changes in the repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting between pipelines will only move the generated slug (the compiled runnable version of your application).
It will not change the GIT repository's content. Therefore, you cannot use git pull to get the latest changes.

You need to pull changes from the app you pushed to, or your GitHub repository if you're using GitHub Sync.

Comment: Thanks, therefore without a GitHub account, which benefits I have with the Promote respect to merge and deploy from staging to production?

Comment: A pipeline gives you the exact same environment between staging and production. No need to rebuild everything, and no risk to have things break because an external dependency changed for example.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this process by creating some bash script or something that will push changes to a repository linked with production? Currently, my repo is on bitbucket so I can't connect it like I can with GitHub.

Comment: You can use Heroku's public API: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-and-release-using-the-api#creating-builds